# Map /phpmyadmin to a different folder in apache with Centos 7

Tags: centos, apache-virtualhost, phpmyadmin

I used the following instructions to install phpMyAdmin into Centos 7 webserver:

```
wget https://files.phpmyadmin.net/phpMyAdmin/4.6.5.2/phpMyAdmin-4.6.5.2-all-languages.tar.gz
tar xvzf phpMyAdmin-4.6.5.2-all-languages.tar.gz
mv phpMyAdmin-4.6.5.2-all-languages phpmyadmin
mv phpmyadmin /var/www/html/
```

Oddly (different from what I read in other questions), phpMyAdmin was installed here:
`/var/www/html/phpmyadmin`
And the phpmyadmin config file is here:
`/var/www/html/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php`

With the default apache configuration, the website is viewed from `/var/www/html` and phpMyAdmin is viewed from `/var/www/html/phpmyadmin`, and looks like this in the URL:

```
http://www.foo.com/phpmyadmin
```

So far so good, all working.

However, I added a virtual host and am now serving the website out of `/var/www/foo.com/public_html`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerAdmin admin@example.com
   DocumentRoot /var/www/foo.com/public_html
   ServerName foo.com
   ServerAlias www.foo.com
   ErrorLog /var/www/foo.com/error.log
</VirtualHost>
```

It works if I `mv  /var/www/html/phpmyadmin  /var/www/foo.com/public_html`, but when logging in via FTP, I don't want the phpmyadmin folder to be visible under the `/var/www/foo.com/public_html` folder.

Is there a way to leave phpmyadmin in its original location at `/var/www/html/phpmyadmin`, but still be accessible via the url `http://foo.com/phpmyadmin` ?

Comment: Ideally you'd have your phpmyadmin files somewhere else and use an include/alias to bring them in to whatever host you want at whatever URL you want.  Don't wanna go all distro war, but check out how Debian sets up apache config and brings in phpmyadmin when installed via apt - much better than what redhat/cent or net/freebsd

Answer (score 2):

You can actually put the folder anywhere as long as there is r-x permissions(not sure about write permissions).

**For Apache v1:**

Edit `/etc/httpd/conf-available/phpmyadmin.conf` or wherever the `httpd` folder is
Add the line `Alias /phpmyadmin /location-of-folder` if it is not already there
Run `systemctl restart httpd`

**For Apache v2:**

Edit `/etc/apache2/conf-available/phpmyadmin.conf` or wherever the `apache2` folder is
Add the line `Alias /phpmyadmin /location-of-folder` if it is not already there
Run `systemctl restart apache2`

Answer (score 1):

Just create symbolic link to your original phpmyadmin folder in 
`/var/www/html` => `ln -s {path of phpmyadmin} /var/www/html/phpmyadmin` folder and configure httpd to Allow symbolic links with `FollowSymLinks` option